# How to program friction in an air hockey game in Cocos2d-x 3.11?

Tags: physics, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a simple air hockey game, and I have a question about friction of puck and puddles with the game scene. How can I do that? I'm using cocos2d-x default physics engine, and the friction setting of physic bodies only applies when they collide.

I've found an [old](https://github.com/lmumar/AirHockey-cocos2d-x) air hockey example project, but it seems that it's ported to cocos2d-x 3.x so it doesn't use built in physics engine.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! We do only one question per question post here, so I removed the second question. You can post another question with your other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized how to do it.
You need to override a method called *Scene::update()* with something like

```
ball->getPhysicsBody()->setVelocity(ball->getPhysicsBody()->getVelocity()*0.995f);
```

And later paste this into your *Scene::init()*, so the *update()* method will be called every frame(?).

```
this->scheduleUpdate();
```

Comment: By this way may slow down the object but its like forever slow down, the velocity is never equal to 0,0

Comment: @TomSawyer yeah, you're right. By the way, this realization worked. Ideally, I should use subtraction with if statement.

Answer (score 1):

the methods you're looking for are:

```
setAngularDamping(float damping);
setLinearDamping(float damping);
```

according to cocos2d-x documentation
both methods are used to simulate fluid or air friction forces on the body.

Comment: what's different between AngularDamping and LinearDamping and what are they?